# how to change the color and font-family in react info banner

Tags: reactjs

```
 const updateProject = () => {
    const project = formik.values;
  
    if (JSON.stringify(initialValues || initialValues.apk ) == JSON.stringify(project)) {
      childalert.info(`No changes were done to the ${project.projectName} project`);

      // props.func("closePopup");
      return null;
    }
```

how to change the color and font family of text 'No changes were done to the project'

Comment: can you please add full code, i donno whats `childalert.info` is?, if its html add css `style={{`fontFamily`:'SOEMTHING'}}`

Comment: const { AlertContatiner, MyAlert: childalert } = useAlert();  childralert is a alert container like a popup or message box but inside childalert how can i give style={{}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import

```
import { Provider as AlertProvider } from 'react-alert'
```

then,

```
childalert.show(<div style={{ 'color': 'blue', 'fontFamily':'arial' }}>
                No changes were done to the ${project.projectName} project
                </div>)
```